# Type-Safe string Parameter for Blazor Component

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorise

Im new to Blazor and really C# in general but i was looking at the Blazorise UI package and noticed they when you want to supply a "Color" property to a button, it will force you to use something like Color="Color.Primary" or Color="Color.Warning". How do i implement this in my own razor component?

Random component that uses the razor Button component

```
<Button @onclick="TestClick2" Color="BtnColor.Danger">Test 3</Button> <--- Color parameter is not working here. It just uses the literal string of 'BtnColor.Danger' instead of 'danger'
```

Button.razor

```
<button class="btn @_btnColorClass">
    @ChildContent
</button>
```

Button.razor.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BlazorServer.UI.Buttons
{
    public partial class Button : ComponentBase
    {
        private string _btnColorClass;
        public static class BtnColor
        {
            public const string Primary = "primary";
            public const string Secondary = "secondary";
            public const string Danger = "danger";
        }

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

        [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
        public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public string Color { get; set; } = BtnColor.Primary;   <------- here?!?

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            _btnColorClass = $"btn-{ Color }";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the parameter as a string (which means you can use pre-defined entries or write in your own), then use constants.

```
public static class BtnColor
{
    public const string Primary = "Primary";
    // ...
}
```

You can also change your parameter to use an enum rather than a string.

```
[Parameter]
public BtnColor Color { get; set; } = BtnColor.Primary;
```

```
public enum BtnColor
{
    Primary,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: when doing `<Button @onclick="TestClick2" Color="BtnColor.Primary">` it doesnt use the public class string value, it just literally puts 'BtnColor.Primary' as the value, instead of  'primary'

Comment: Use an `@`. `@BtnColor.Primary`

Comment: That errors out with 'The name BtnColor does not exist in the current context.'

Comment: In your case your BtnColor class is inside the Button class. So `Button.BtnColor....`

Comment: That works. Is there an easy way to not have to type Color="@Button.BtnColor.Primary" ? Instead something like Color="Color.Primary"

Comment: If the parameter expects a string, you must use a `@` so that razor understands you mean to pass in c# rather than a string literal.

Comment: If you are referring to not having to put the namespace, add the using to your `_Imports.razor` file

Comment: @user616 - you put the BtnColor class _inside_ the Button class. So the full name becomes `Button.BtnColor.Primary`  (everywhere outside the Button class).

Answer (score 0):

```
css classes:
    .primary{}
    .secondary{}
    .danger{}
    
color enum:
    public enum Color{ Primary, Secondary, Danger}

Parameter:
[Parameter]
public Color Color { get; set; } = Color.Primary;

html:
<button class="@Color.ToString().ToLower()">@childcontent</button>
```

Comment: This is close to what im looking for, i just need the enum to give me strings back instead of an integer. Type-Safe Parameters for Blazor Components

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Color
    {
        Primary,
        Secondary,
        Danger
    }

public static class ColorExtensions
    {
        public static string GetString(this Color me)
        {
            switch (me)
            {
                case Color.Primary:
                    return "Primary";
                case Color.Secondary:
                    return "Secondary";
                case Color.Danger:
                    return "Danger";
                default:
                    return "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
Color color = Color.Primary;
string output = color.GetString();
```